# How to crop ListBoxItem's content and fit it to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Sometimes content of my ListBoxItem is wider than the listbox, so it is cropped by ListBox. That is fine but the gradient background of ListBoxItem is not stretched to the listbox width but to the width of ListBoxItem's content. With the code below I am trying to force gradient to be edge-to-edge of ListBox. ListBox has dynamic width so I can not predefine ListBoxItem's width. What am I missing?

```
<Style x:Key="MyListbox" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
```

and

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyData}" >
       <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
...
         <Setter Property="Background">
          <Setter.Value>
           <LinearGradientBrush>
             <GradientStop Color="#ffffff" Offset="0"/>
             <GradientStop Color="#000000" Offset="1"/>
           </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain it's the effect you're going for, but you could try adding this to your `Grid` in the `DataTemplate`.

```
<Grid Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}">
```

Essentially it's trying to locate the `ListBox` parent, and if successful, will grab the `Width` property, which will ensure your `ListBoxItems` are all of the same width (that of the `ListBox`). That worked for me in a quick test project.

If what you're after is just a simple gradient from edge to edge on the `ListBox` itself, you should be able to get that effect by styling the `ListBox` background and giving the `ListBoxItems` transparent backgrounds. I assumed you just wanted the gradient on the `ListBoxItems`.

Comment: Thank you! That is the solution. I could not have that background on ListBox because only selected item should have the gradient background. Worked perfectly.